# Option Numbers=Lining not working any more with font Constantia after MikTek Update

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I need to use the font Constantia and thus compile my document with LuaLaTeX using `\usepackage{fontspec}`(Editor is TeXStudio). As I do not like the OldStyle numbers, I use `\setmainfont[Numbers=Lining]{Constantia}`. So far, this worked perfectly, but since I updated MikTeX yesterday I get the error:

```
OpenType feature 'Numbers=Uppercase' (lnum) not(fontspec) available for font 'Constantia' with script(fontspec) 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=Lining]{Constantia}

\begin{document}

1234567890

\end{document}
```

It produces the following output:

[image: Numbers are set in OldStyle]

The font itself can't be the problem, as I tested it in Word where I can change the behavior:

[image: Output generated with Word and Font-Option Lining]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The luatex 1.10.1 used in miktex has a bug affecting font usage.

I already made a bug report for this and suggested that the miktex goes back to 1.10.0: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/353

If you are in pressing need you could install texlive 2019 beside your miktex and use this until the problem has been resolved.

Comment: Thank you very much@UlrikeFischer , it is not that urgend, so guess I will wait for the new update 1.11. Do you know when this will be released?

Comment: Update: Today there were new Versions of `lualibs` and `loaotfload`. Unfortunately the problem persists.

Comment: The problem is in the binary. There is nothing that luaotfload can do here. You can only add a comment to https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/353 that the issue is really a problem and wait (it is holiday time currently ...), or switch to texlive.

Comment: Done, thank you for the support.