# Fontspec cannot find OpenType features

Tags: luatex, fontspec, opentype

And I’m back with more fontspec trouble. Recently, I asked a question about how to access a particular character variant using fontspec ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501833/difficulty-accessing-character-variant-with-lualatex-and-fontspec)). [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)’s solution — to put a newer version of the font in my local `texmf` tree then call `mktexlsr` and `luaotfload-tool -u -f` — worked wonderfully for a time, and then broke later the same day.  Now I am unable to load *any* OpenType features, not even small caps. Here’s a minimal example:

[image: 1. a/b 2. a/b 3. a/b (LaTeX)]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode} 

\addfontfeatures{ 
    Script={Latin},
    Numbers={OldStyleOff, Proportional},
}

\begin{document}
    1. a/b \addfontfeatures{StylisticSet={10},Numbers={Lowercase,Proportional}}
    2. a/b 
    3. \textsc{a/b}
\end{document}
```

When I ask for the same features with another software (I think MS Word generates its own small caps, so I’m using Publisher), everything is fine:

[image: 1. a/b 2. a/b 3. a/b (MS Publisher)]

Similar problems persist even with system fonts *e.g.* Cambria or Candara.

I don’t know whether it’s useful information or not, but just in case, the log file flags up the following warnings,

```
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache loaded from C:/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/
MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc.
luaotfload | aux : no font with id -1
luaotfload | aux : no font with id -1
luaotfload | aux : no font with id -1
luaotfload | aux : no font with id -1

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'Junicode(0)' created for font 'Junicode'
(fontspec)             with options [Ligatures=TeX].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Junicode:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Junicode/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;
"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Junicode/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;
"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (bx/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Junicode/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig
;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 

LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 37.
luaotfload | aux : no font with id -1

Package fontspec Warning: Font "Junicode" does not contain requested Script
(fontspec)                "Latin".


Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Numbers=LowercaseOff' (onum) not
(fontspec)                available for font 'Junicode' with script '' and
(fontspec)                language 'Default'
```

as well as a further number of the type below.

```
Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Variant=10' (ss10) not available
(fontspec)                for font 'Junicode' with script 'CustomDefault' and
(fontspec)                language 'Default'.
```

I’m really baffled here, especially since the problem appears to be restricted to my machine. Does anyone know what could be going on?

**Edit:** This is a known issue with `luatex 1.10.1` in MiKTeX. See [this tex.sx post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504285/option-numbers-lining-not-working-any-more-with-font-constantia-after-miktek-upd) and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/353).

Comment: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/353

Comment: Thank you! I’ve added the relevant reading and will now mark this post as duplicate.